# git custom commit id?

Tags: git, commit, sha1

Rather theoretical question, but if someone knows practical implementations, I would love to hear them.

As we know git uses SHA1 for commit ids.
Their problem is that you cannot quickly say anything by just looking to this key. Yes, you can find out almost anything about this git commit id with git help, but you cannot say anything about it by just **looking** at it. And sometimes it would be handy.

If the commit id was SHA1+authorid+creation_time it would be simpler to use.

I'm sure there are simple reasons why git doesn't have this type of commit id, but I don't know which ones. Does anyone know?

Comment: It seems to me there are a lot of assumptions about what's "easier to use", that rest entirely on your tool setup.  The SHA ID is very much meant to serve the technical needs of the system - it's probably the least user-friendly thing to which users are exposed.  So I for one am not convinced that mixing user-facing data into that particular data element is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no fundamental or technical reason Git could not have appended this information to each hash.  It would add no capabilities not already present, though, since you can simply create an annotated tag whose name you control, that then contains the hash ID of the desired commit, along with any auxiliary data you care to insert.

In other words, what you suggest could work, and perhaps remove the need for some tags, at the expense of even-more-unwieldy hash IDs.  Whether that's a good tradeoff (an improvement over the current situation) is a matter of opinion. :-)

(For a description of what Git, or any other similar VCS, requires from the hash, see [chapter 4, Distributing Repositories, of my extremely-slow-progress book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).)

Comment: Also, Git uses the same type of ID for trees and blobs, which might not have a definitive author or creation time.

Comment: @DanielH: true. I'd imagine the core part of Git might completely ignore the appended data, though as Git acquires SHA-256 handling (which requires keeping multiple hash index tables) it could also become possible to keep and check additional data. (But making them variable-length is a bit sticky, in terms of the speed-critical parts.)

Comment: There would always be a problem of what extra info to encode in a hash. So the approach implemented in Git -- encode whatever you need using free-form keywords in the commit message itself, and then parse them out when you need them -- is more sensible. Sure, it does not have that "…just by looking at a hash" property but its way more flexible.

Comment: @torek any way to subscribe to the news about the book's progress? (I should say I've already lamented the impossibility to follow the answers of a particular SO user to questions tagged with a particular tag; I mean you and `[git]`).

Comment: @kostix: not really - it's a side project; most of the initial work happened between jobs, when a startup I was working for went under. There's no publisher, hence no deadline, etc. :-)